# C# and .NET frameworki a

Tags: c#, .net, frameworks

I am going to start work with a company that works on a .NET framework and i am a professional java developer and i think i should switch to .NET because i cant see any bright future with java anymore.
My questions:
Now i have decided to move to .NET, what things i should learn as a total beginner. Should i learn C# or i should understand basics of .NET first?? as i know only that .Net is a framework and c# is one of language run on it. I am only interested in C# as it like java not in VB or any other.
please tell me what i am suppose to learn and please refer to me some books.
thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/212263/how-do-i-move-from-java-to-c

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2068669/migrating-from-java-to-c-sharp

Comment: The company you are going to work for should have a plan for your conversion, because they know you're a Java person, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are correct in your understanding that .Net is the underlying portable framework which is supported via multiple languages such as C#,VB etc. If you are looking for a Java equivalent in terms of programming language then C# is exactly what you want to be working with.

One of the best books for C# out there is [C# via CLR](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0735667454) that teaches you C# with an understanding of the underlying CLR. It is more of an intermediate-advanced proficiency book but the basics should be easy to latch on to given your Java background.